# I can't post to an api on my cpanel account

Tags: api, postman, cpanel

I have APIs, stored them on cpanel web. The APIs on web A is working completely. then I copied to web B with same setting (I changed the database user, host etc)

I can GET that API but I can't post that API on web B, while APIs on web A work completely.

I tried to re-copy the file, analyzing the database and conf.ini file but still can't POST.

PS: I'm new to cPanel, my boss asked me to set that API on web first, migrate later.

Comment: please check the POST method configuration in web B's host maybe it is not allowed and
also check the host fire wall.

Comment: What do you get in the API response? What is the body, and what is the response code? You should be able to see that in a tool like curl or Postman. If you can provide some PHP error logs too, that would be useful - presently this is very broad, and liable to be put on hold.